# Getting temporary value out of map

Tags: rust

I am trying to achieve the following:
Given an array slice of `str`s:

- convert each element to a *sorted* `Vec<&str>` (primarily because that is the output of `.graphemes`)
- collect the output of that map into a `Vec<Vec<&str>>` (again, the `&str` choice is because of `.graphemes`, the vector of vectors is intentional.

The error returned is that `candidate_graphemes` references a temporary value. I *kind of* understand why, but I would appreciate an explanation, and I'm not entirely sure how to fix it. I'm fairly new to rust...

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use unicode_segmentation::UnicodeSegmentation;

pub fn anagrams_for<'a>(word: &str, possible_anagrams: &[&'a str]) -> HashSet<&'a str> {
    let sorted_possible_anagrams = possible_anagrams
        .iter()
        .map(|candidate| {
            let mut candidate_graphemes = candidate
                .to_lowercase()
                .graphemes(true)
                .collect::<Vec<&str>>();
             candidate_graphemes.sort();
             candidate_graphemes
        })
        .collect::<Vec<Vec<&str>>>();
    let mut results = HashSet::new();
    results
}
```

Comment: The issue is that `to_lowercase()` creates a `String`. These `String`s need to be kept somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in your map closure, you can see that you are using the `.to_lowercase()` method on a `&str` which returns a `String`.

This string belongs to the closure.

The allocation is *needed* because the `&str` is a shared reference therefor you cannot mutate the `str` directly through it.

When you call the `.graphemes` method, you get back an iterator of `&str` but those references are actually different form the first one: their lifetime is constrained inside of the closure while the lifetime of your original references (the `&str`s in `possible_anagrams`) have the lifetime `'a` (defined in your function's generic parameters).

```rust
/* ... */ .map(|candidate| {
    let lowercase_string = candidate.to_lowercase(); // here is the `String`
    let graphemes = lowercase_string.graphemes(true); // Here is the `Iterator<Item = &'b str>` where 'b is the lifetime of `lowercase_string`
    let mut vec = graphemes.collect::<Vec<&str>>()
    vec.sort();
    vec // The lifetime 'b ends here (so `lowercase_string` gets dropped) but you're trying to move references to this `String` out of the closure.
}) /* ... */
```

This is why your code doesn't compile.

A possible fix would be to return `String`s

```rust
let mut candidate_graphemes = candidate
    .to_lowercase()
    .graphemes(true)
    .map(|s| String::from(s)) // add this
    .collect::<Vec<String>>(); // `String`s do not hold any lifetimes, they are simply moved out of the closure
```

And all the returned strings would be lowercased. A downside to this is that all those `String`s would need to be allocated on the heap. This would make your function much slower.

Another fix would be to ask `possible_anagrams` to always contain lowercased `&str`s. This would prevent your map from needing to allocate `String`s for each candidate/grapheme.

```rust
let mut candidate_graphemes = candidate
    // .to_lowercase() we know candidate is already lowercase
    .graphemes(true)
    .collect::<Vec<&str>>(); // now, the `&str`s have the correct lifetime of `'a`
candidate_graphemes.sort();
candidate_graphemes
```

Comment: That makes sense - thank you very much, particularly for the explanation!